# Calculate difference between two DateOnly structs (C#)

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

In .NET 6 the `DateOnly` struct was introduced. How can one calculate the difference between two `DateOnly` structs (for example the total number of days)?

For two `DateTime` structs this can be done as follows:

```
    private int DaysDifferenceDateTime(DateTime dateTime1, DateTime dateTime2)
    {
        return (dateTime1 - dateTime2).Days;
    }
```

However if one tries this, it will not work:

```
    private int DaysDifferenceDateOnly(DateOnly dateOnly1, DateOnly dateOnly2)
    {
        return (dateOnly1 - dateOnly2).Days; // this is invalid code
    }
```

A possible workaround is to convert both `DateOnly` to `DateTime`:

```
    private int DaysDifferenceDateOnlyConverted(DateOnly dateOnly1, DateOnly dateOnly2)
    {
        return (new DateTime(dateOnly1.Year, dateOnly1.Month, dateOnly1.Day) - new DateTime(dateOnly2.Year, dateOnly2.Month, dateOnly2.Day)).Days;
    }
```

But is there a more elegant way to calculate the differences?

Comment: There is place for an extension method here

Comment: You can always cast a `DateOnly` to a `DateTime` (with `.ToDateTime`). But it's weird these methods and operators don't exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing the reason there's no implementation of the subtraction operator for that type is because there's no `DateSpan` type and a `TimeSpan` is a bit misleading.

What you can do is just to subtract the `DayNumber` from each other.

```
private int DaysDifferenceDateOnly(DateOnly dateOnly1, DateOnly dateOnly2)
{
    return dateOnly1.DayNumber - dateOnly2.DayNumber;
}
```